# AnkhSVN - Latest Version

Tags: visual-studio-2008, svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

What do you guys think of the new Ankh SVN /w Tortoise SVN?

This is my first time using source control and all I used it for was the very basics. It worked well... At first...

Somewhere along the way everything got really screwed up and I had to uninstall it. It seems like you have to use it a certain way or everything will screw up... Maybe I just don't know the concepts, but there seems to be no room for error or it's time to uninstall.

Answer (score 2):

i've been using both for a while now without any issues. i found the concept of not having exclusive checkout hard to get used to after sourcesafe but once you've done a few merges the power of SVN is clear.

its also worth looking at http://www.visualsvn.com/ especially the free server.

Josh